# Reading the closing of 12 volt circuit over RS232

Tags: rs232, automotive, 12v, port

Car trouble.  I suspect the fuel injector circuit.  I am trying to construct a com port reader that will place a timestamp into a log on the closing the 12v fuel injector circuit.

The fuel injector is a simple normally open 12v circuit of 2 wires.  The + is tied into the ignition switch.  The ground is held open by the ECM (Electronic Control Module). When it is time to squirt fuel into the cylinder, the ECM pulses/flashes the ground to complete the circuit.

I am planning on using Eltima's Serial Port Monitor to record the event of the closed circuit with a timestamp on a single injector and store the data into a log so that I can evaluate and analyze the data.

Originally, I thought I would simply run pin 3 of a DB9 to a back probe on the injector and run the engine.  But with the circuit always powered by 12 volts, I would get a reading on pin 3 coinciding with the ignition switch and not with the pulsing ground.

Do you have any ideas on how to read the pulsing ground on the fuel injector?

Answer (score 1):

You could try isolating the switching signal with an opto coupler.
[image]

Every time the ECM pulls the injector to ground a small current (about 10mA) goes through the internal LED and turns on the output transistor.

The pulse width/timing could be measured using a small microcontroller and converted to serial data.

Comment: Take precautions to prevent the inductive kick-back from the fuel injector from frying your opto-coupler LED.  Since a waveform from a fuel-injector doesn't resemble a serial data stream in any way, it is not at all clear how you can convince your serial port monitor to detect and record the pulses?

Comment: @RichardCrowley. Thanks for that. As far as how to convert the pulse into a serial data stream I would add a small microcontroller to measure the pulse width and timing between pulses and send out an appropriate signal. I've added this to the circuit.

Comment: It is my understanding that a change in the voltage on pin 3 will be read by the port monitor -- the monitor should record the change as junk (i.e. no intelligible data, no stop bit, etc) but what I am interested in is the EVENT of the change and not the transfer of the data (or in this case, non-data). 

I am hoping that reading the change will allow me to determine the start of the pulse, the duration, and frequency per second or minute.

Comment: Use one of the RS-232 flow-control pins - they are digital levels; there is no data protocol on them. "Back in the old days" when we needed quick & dirty digital I/O from a PC, we often used those.